# nodejs v 0.11: cannot build native extensions for websockets

Tags: node.js, npm

I just upgraded my node's version to v0.11.4, and now my `npm install websocket` fails to build naive extension. The top part of the error output is below. Has anyone seen this?

> websocket@1.0.8 install /home/akonsu/projects/myproj/node_modules/websocket
>   node install.js

[websocket v1.0.8] Attempting to compile native extensions.
child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
make: Entering directory `/home/akonsu/projects/myproj/node_modules/websocket/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
../src/validation.cc:117:34: error: ‘Arguments’ does not name a type
   static Handle New(const Arguments& args)
                                  ^
../src/validation.cc:117:45: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘args’ with no type [-fpermissive]
   static Handle New(const Arguments& args)
                                             ^
../src/validation.cc:125:42: error: ‘Arguments’ does not name a type
   static Handle IsValidUTF8(const Arguments& args)
                                          ^
../src/validation.cc:125:53: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘args’ with no type [-fpermissive]
   static Handle IsValidUTF8(const Arguments& args)
                                                     ^
In file included from ../src/validation.cc:8:0:
/home/akonsu/.node-gyp/0.11.14/deps/v8/include/v8.h: In static member function ‘static void Validation::Initialize(v8::Handle)’:
/home/akonsu/.node-gyp/0.11.14/deps/v8/include/v8.h:816:13: error: ‘v8::HandleScope::HandleScope()’ is protected
   V8_INLINE HandleScope() {}
             ^
../src/validation.cc:108:17: error: within this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `websocket` module on npm is currently not compatible with node v0.11.x, which is an unstable branch. Try node v0.10.x.